# Converting vim substitution with back references to sed, awk or similar unix command

Tags: regex, unix, vim, awk, sed

Hi I have a command which I have been using to process text files in vim; looking for a string R1 then deleting 3 lines, 2 below the line with that string.
This works fine in vim however for large files it is very slow:

```
:1,$s/\(r1.*\n\)\(\(.*\n\){2}\)\(\(.*\n\)\{3}\)/\1\2/g
```

Example:

```
R1                  30049              109769            109769 
                                       101598            281921 
                                 6.56608e+006      2.82861e+006 
                                 1.19658e+006      1.19658e+006 
                                      -515145           -515145 
                                      -223257            627520 
                                      -101598           -281921 
                                -6.56608e+006     -2.82861e+006 
                                       23.125            23.125 
                                        271.7            272.46 
                                          500               500
```

would become:

```
R1                  30049              109769            109769 
                                       101598            281921 
                                 6.56608e+006      2.82861e+006 
                                      -101598           -281921 
                                -6.56608e+006     -2.82861e+006 
                                       23.125            23.125 
                                        271.7            272.46 
                                          500               500
```

Can this command (or similar) be run in sed or awk in a unix terminal any quicker?

Many thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `:g/R1/.+3,.+5d` in `vim` (instead of the demonic regex)?  That should be rather fast, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with sed:

```
sed -n '/^R1/{p;n;p;n;p;n;n;n;n};p;' file.txt
```

To edit the file in place with a backup:

```
sed -n -i.bak '/^R1/{p;n;p;n;p;n;n;n;n};p;' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a multi-line regular expression (which indeed can be slow), you can solve this with `:global` in Vim:

```
:global/^R1/.+3,.+5delete _
```

This searches for all lines starting with `R1`, and then deletes three to five lines down (into the black-hole register `_`).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through perl,

```
$ perl -00pe 's/(\bR1.*\n(?:.*\n){2})(.*\n){3}/\1/g' file
R1                  30049              109769            109769 
                                       101598            281921 
                                 6.56608e+006      2.82861e+006 
                                      -101598           -281921 
                                -6.56608e+006     -2.82861e+006 
                                       23.125            23.125 
                                        271.7            272.46 
                                          500               500
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substutions on a single line but for anything else just use awk:

```
$ awk '/R1/{start=NR+3;end=start+2} NR<start || NR>end' file
R1                  30049              109769            109769
                                       101598            281921
                                 6.56608e+006      2.82861e+006
                                      -101598           -281921
                                -6.56608e+006     -2.82861e+006
                                       23.125            23.125
                                        271.7            272.46
                                          500               500
```

The above says to start deleting 3 lines after the line containing R1 (NR+3) and stop 2 lines after that (start+2). If you have some other range or some other pattern or some other condition to handle, the tweak to make it work is clear and simple. Try adjusting a sed solution to delete 20 lines instead of 3.

If for some reason you prefer the brevity of the sed solution, just use single-char variable names and lose the white space:

```
awk '/R1/{s=NR+3;e=s+2}NR<s||NR>e' file
```

and it's briefer than the sed one, but still much more maintainable, extensible, etc as awk solutions for multi-line problems always are.